# Compile warning when returning retval with pthread_exit()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have the following:

```
void *Thrd(void *data)
{
    int ret;
    ret = myfunc();
    pthread_exit((void *)ret);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;

    pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, Thrd, &data);

    pthread_join(txThread, (void **)&status);
    if (status)
        printf("*** thread failed with error %d\n", status);
}
```

It works and I'm able to read *status* but I'm getting the following warning at compile:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void* Thrd(void*)’:
test.cpp:468:26: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

this is the line with `pthread_exit()`

I simply can't find what is wrong :( ...

Comment: How comes you don't find what is wrong. The compiler tells you: "cast to pointer from integer of different size". What is so difficult to understand?

Answer (score 3):

So, you are trying to return an integer value from a thread function. A POSIX thread function can only return `void*`.

There are a few ways to return a value from another thread:

1) You can cast an integer to `void*` and back, provided `void*` is wide enough to hold the value without truncation:

```
void *Thrd(void *vdata) {
    int value = ...;
    void* thread_return_value = (void*)value;
    return thread_return_value;
}
// ...
void* status;
pthread_join(txThread, &status);
int value = (int)status;
```

2) Pass the address of the return value to the thread function and make the thread function set that value:

```
struct Data { int return_value; };

void *Thrd(void *vdata) {
    // ...
    int value = ...;
    struct Data* data = vdata;
    data->return_value = value;
    return NULL;
}
// ...
pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, Thrd, &data);
pthread_join(txThread, NULL);
int value = data->return_value;
```

3) Let the thread allocate the return value. The other thread that joins() needs to read that value and deallocate it:

```
void *Thrd(void *vdata) {
    // ...
    int* value = malloc(sizeof *value);
    *value = ...;
    return value;
}
// ...
void* status;
pthread_join(txThread, &status);
int* value = status;
// ...
free(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
pthread_exit((void *)ret);
```

write this:

```
pthread_exit((void *)&ret);
```

In "pthread_exit((void *)ret)", you're telling `pthread_exit` there's a return value at address `pertaining to the value contained in ret variable`. You want the result to be stored at the address of ret, so it should be `pthread_exit(&ret)`.

Now `ret` is a local integer variable. Its preferable if you write:

```
int *ret=malloc(sizeof(int));

if(ret==NULL)

  //handle the error

*ret=func();

pthread_exit(ret);
```

And don't forget to `free` the pointer.

Comment: And now you return the __address__ of a local variable. Whereas the author wants to return the __value__.

Comment: That's dangerous. :) But I was just fixing the warning message. Focus on the question. But, yeah, I will edit it to reflect this point too.

Comment: well, such a fix changes the behaviour in such a way, that it is no longer useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a non-pointer to a pointer - that might be why you are getting the warning.
Perhaps you can modify your code to use a `int*` instead of your `int ret`, and cast that to a `void*`.

Edit : As Tony The Lion mentioned.